# Jumping from one Jframe to another

Tags: java, jframe

Im new to programming and im trying to make two Jframes and move from one to the other on click. This is the code so far that i have on button click.

```
 private void bFindActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
     Search newSearch = new Search();
     newSearch.setVisible(true);
     this.setVisible(false);
}
```

From this i get a new window and the current window closes and it is visible with a transition. What im trying to do is move from the same window. If someone could show me the right way it would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: If you are new to programming, I'd suggest avoiding Swing unless you have a good reason (e.g. a teacher is making you). While the skills you gain will be *somewhat* transferable, Swing itself is basically dead. Most people would not choose Swing if they were starting from scratch today.

Comment: "Im new to programming and im trying to make two Jframes" - if you're new to programming you should be careful about diving into gui development as this can lead to trying to take multiple steps at once which will make you fail. Besides that, I'm not sure I understand what you're after. What do you mean by "move from the same window"?

Comment: @Michael Im on my first year and i have learnt the basics and right now our lessons are based on gui development and no we havent learnt about swings yet..

Comment: @Thomas im building this from netbeans. by set visibility the current jframe closes and the next jframe opens .. what i wanted to mean was instead i want to stay on the same jframe and display the next jframe content.

Comment: In that case use panels etc. and have a look at layout managers, e.g. CardLayout.